# Unit Testing in a "no setter" world

Tags: unit-testing, domain-driven-design

I do not consider myself a DDD expert but, as a solution architect, do try to apply best practices whenever possible.  I know there is a lot of discussion around the pro's and con's of the no (public) setter "style" in DDD and I can see both sides of the argument.  My problem is that I work on a team with a wide diversity in skills, knowledge and experience meaning that I cannot trust that every developer will do things the "right" way.  For instance, if our domain objects are designed so that changes to the object's internal state is performed by a method but provide public property setters, someone will inevitable set the property instead of calling the method.  Use this example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Boolean IsPublished
    {
        get { return PublishDate != null; }
    }

    public DateTime? PublishDate { get; set; }

    public void Publish()
    {
        if (IsPublished)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Already published.");

        PublishDate = DateTime.Today;

        Raise(new PublishedEvent());
    }
}
```

My solution has been to make property setters private which is possible because the ORM we are using to hydrate the objects uses reflection so it is able to access private setters.  However, this presents a problem when trying to write unit tests.  For example, when I want to write a unit test that verifies the requirement that we can't re-publish, I need to indicate that the object has already been published.  I can certainly do this by calling Publish twice, but then my test is assuming that Publish is implemented correctly for the first call. That seems a little smelly.

Let's make the scenario a little more real-world with the following code:

```
public class Document
{
    public Document(String title)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
            throw new ArgumentException("title");

        Title = title;
    }

    public String ApprovedBy { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? ApprovedOn { get; private set; }
    public Boolean IsApproved { get; private set; }
    public Boolean IsPublished { get; private set; }
    public String PublishedBy { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? PublishedOn { get; private set; }
    public String Title { get; private set; }

    public void Approve(String by)
    {
        if (IsApproved)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Already approved.");

        ApprovedBy = by;
        ApprovedOn = DateTime.Today;
        IsApproved = true;

        Raise(new ApprovedEvent(Title));
    }

    public void Publish(String by)
    {
        if (IsPublished)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Already published.");

        if (!IsApproved)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot publish until approved.");

        PublishedBy = by;
        PublishedOn = DateTime.Today;
        IsPublished = true;

        Raise(new PublishedEvent(Title));
    }
}
```

I want to write unit tests that verify:

- I cannot publish unless the Document has been approved
- I cannot re-publish a Document
- When published, the PublishedBy and PublishedOn values are properly
  set
- When publised, the PublishedEvent is raised

Without access to the setters, I cannot put the object into the state needed to perform the tests.  Opening access to the setters defeats the purpose of preventing access.

How do(have) you solve(d) this problem?

Comment: The more I think about this, the more I think that your entire problem is having methods with side-effects. Or rather, a mutable immutable object. In a DDD-world, should you not return a new Document object from both Approve and Publish, rather than updating the internal state of this object?

Comment: Quick question, which O/RM are you using. I'm a big fan of EF but declaring setters as protected does rub me the wrong way a bit.

Comment: We have a mix right now because of the free-range development I have been charged with wrangling in.  Some ADO.NET using AutoMapper to hydrate from a DataReader, a couple of Linq-to-SQL models (that will be the next to replace) and some new EF models.

Comment: Calling Publish twice is not smelly at all and is the way to do it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> I cannot put the object into the state needed to perform the tests.

If you cannot put the object into the state needed to perform a test, then you cannot put the object into the state in production code, so there's no need to test **that** state. Obviously, this isn't true in your case, you **can** put your object into the needed state, just call Approve.

- I cannot publish unless the Document has been approved: write a test that calling publish before calling approve causes the right error without changing the object state.

  ```
  void testPublishBeforeApprove() {
      doc = new Document("Doc");
      AssertRaises(doc.publish, ..., NotApprovedException);
  }
  ```
- I cannot re-publish a Document: write a test that approves an object, then calling publish once succeed, but second time causes the right error without changing the object state.

  ```
  void testRePublish() {
      doc = new Document("Doc");
      doc.approve();
      doc.publish();
      AssertRaises(doc.publish, ..., RepublishException);
  }
  ```
- When published, the PublishedBy and PublishedOn values are properly set: write a test that calls approve then call publish, assert that the object state changes correctly

  ```
  void testPublish() {
      doc = new Document("Doc");
      doc.approve();
      doc.publish();
      Assert(doc.PublishedBy, ...);
      ...
  }
  ```
- When publised, the PublishedEvent is raised: hook to the event system and set a flag to make sure it's called

You also need to write test for approve.

In other word, don't test the relation between internal fields and IsPublished and IsApproved, your test would be quite fragile if you do that since changing your field would mean changing your tests code, so the test would be quite pointless. Instead you should test the relationship between calls of public methods, this way, even if you modify the fields you wouldn't need to modify the test.

Comment: When Approve breaks, several tests break. You're no longer testing a unit of code, you're testing the full implementation.

Comment: I share pdr's concern which is why I hesitated going this direction.  Yes, it seems cleanest, but I don't like having multiple reasons an individual test can fail.

Comment: I've yet to see a unit test which could only fail for a single possible reason. Also, you can put the "state manipulation" parts of the test into a `setup()` method --- not the test itself.

Comment: @PeterK.: Putting something in the setup doesn't stop it failing the test. And he has different state prerequisites for different tests, so it's not an option anyway. And, while you are correct that all tests can fail for multiple reasons, you should strive for each change to only affect one test. If changing the approve method, deliberately, breaks testing on the publish method, your tests are too brittle.

Comment: @pdr: Either that, or your design is too brittle! :-)

Comment: Why is depending on `approve()` somehow brittle, yet depending on `setApproved(true)` somehow not?  `approve()` is a legitimate dependency in the tests because it is a dependency in the requirements.  If the dependency only existed in the tests, that would be another issue.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt: Come on. Seriously? First: Approve() has logic and every likelihood of changing. setApprove() ... not so much. Second: The entire question is based on a desire to avoid setters entirely, so we're not discussing setApprove().

Comment: @pdr, if you aren't suggesting `setApprove`, what are you proposing as the alternative to calling `approve()`?

Comment: @pdr, how would you test a stack class? Would you try to test the `push()` and `pop()` methods independently?

Comment: @WinstonEwert: What I'm suggesting is that the logic in Approve and Publish should be extracted into another (DocumentTimestamper?) class which receives the data necessary to create a new Document object with a new timestamp and name in the relevant place, having done some pre-validation on that data, removing the need for heavy testing on either method within Document.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: A stack is different, because it's very mutable (and the aim here is immutability) but, unless there was a good reason not to, I would allow for a constructor which allows for initial objects on the stack.

Comment: @pdr, the aim here is immutability? Where do you get that? The classes in question from the OP are mutable. You certainly could go immutable here, but that seems a whole different question then one given by the OP.

Comment: @pdr, as for the stack, is there really a difference between testing by using `push` vs using the constructor to initialize the state? From my perspective, either way you're trusting one piece of code to setup the correct state for your second piece of code.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: Right from the title: In a no-setter world. What is the point of not having setters if not immutability? As for the stack, yes. Because I also have to test push() when items already exist. If those items have been created by push(), how reliable is my test?

Comment: @pdr: No setters just means that the user of my class cannot *directly* set the state of a field. It can still be set indirectly through other public methods, as in this example.

Comment: @jhewlett: Ok, fine. I'm not sure I agree that's a good idea, but it's irrelevant. The fact still remains that a service, encapsulated by Document should be doing the hard graft. If not, how much logic do you allow in the entity before crying SRP? I come back to this article: http://blog.pluralsight.com/2012/03/02/whats-the-single-responsibility-of-an-entity-in-domain-driven-design/

Comment: @pdr, regarding the stack: my point is that you can't test methods of the object independently of one another. I can't test pop independently of either the constructor or push. So I don't see it as a problem that one method is tested assuming that another method is correct.

Comment: @pdr, I'm having some dissonance between your comments and the articles. You talk about services, whereas the article talks about value objects. I'm not sure it changes the question. Do we bring our objects to a known state, and then test it? Or do we perform operations on an object, and figure the state is an implementation detail?

Comment: @WinstonEwert: A Value Object is simply where his logic had gone, in the example he was discussing. The point is the question: What is the single responsibility of an entity in DDD? All logic beyond that should be passed on to other classes, where they can be tested without worrying about the state of the object they're working on (eg. `_timestamper.Publish(_name, ref _approved, ref _published);`) You can tidy that example up any number of ways, the point is that now you have one line to test in Document and all the logic (inc. the tricksy DateTime.Now) is in a stateless class.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: Please, let's move off the stack; it's a very different example and, while I don't agree entirely with what you're saying, it's complicating the discussion which is already 20 messages too long.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: Giving that some more thought, in this specific case, it *could* -- if desirable -- be quickly refactored such that Timestamp became a value object, where the Document contains two (published and approved), there is a null value to the timestamp (x.IsNull, as opposed to x == null), and Timestamp has a method Set(name, checkNull, checkNotNull) which receives an array of timestamps that should be null and timestamps that shouldn't be null as a validation check. Thus `_published.Set(name, shouldNotBeNull: new[] { _approved }, shouldBeNull: new[] { _published });`

Comment: @pdr: Oh man! You are overcomplicating it so much! What Lie Ryan presented is the way to do it.

Comment: @Peri: Trying to be SOLID is overcomplicating? I despair for this industry sometimes.

Comment: It's already SOLID. And you propose adding constructor only for tests. Is this SOLID in your opinion? The example with Stack is a great one. You test Pop after calling Push.

Comment: @Peri: How is it S or O? And where did I propose a constructor for testing?

Comment: Sorry about the constructor comment. It was proposed under. My bad.

Comment: This class is very simple. This is a document that handles itself and raises events for other parts of the system to handle that events. It's only responsibility is to work on it's own attributes. That how it is S. And if you ask about O. (why don't you ask about L I and D?). Did you notice Raise calls? You can add as many handlers as you want without modifying any code. This is O. I wonder how you would test ToString on Person class. Will you depend on ctor setting first and last name correctly and use it to setup person object? If yes why can't you depend on approve in this answer?

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach is to create a constructor of the class that allows the internal properties to be set on instantiation:

```
 public Document(
  String approvedBy,
  DateTime? approvedOn,
  Boolean isApproved,
  Boolean isPublished,
  String publishedBy,
  DateTime? publishedOn,
  String title)
{
  ApprovedBy = approvedBy;
  ApprovedOn = approvedOn;
  IsApproved = isApproved;
  IsApproved = isApproved;
  PublishedBy = publishedBy;
  PublishedOn = publishedOn;
}
```

Comment: This does not scale well at all.  My object could have many more properties with any number of them having or not having values at any given point in the object's lifecycle.  I follow the principal that constructors contain parameters for properties that are required for the object to be in a valid initial state or dependencies an object requires to function. The purpose of the properties in the example are to capture the current state as the object is manipulated. Having a constructor with every property or overloads with different combinations is a huge smell and, as I said, doesn't scale.

Comment: Understood. Your example did not mention many more properties, and the number in the example is "on the cusp" of having this as a valid approach.  

It seems that this is telling you something about your design: you *can't* put your object into **any** valid state on instantiation. That means you need to put it into a valid initial state, and them manipulate it into the right state for test. That implies [Lie Ryan's answer is the way to go](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/191036/2722).

Comment: Even if object has one property and will never change this solution is bad. What stops anyone from using this constructor in production? How will you mark this constructor [TestOnly]?

Comment: Why is it bad in production?  (Really, I'd like to know). Sometimes it's necessary to recreate the precise state of an object at creation... not just a single valid initial object.

Comment: It's bad in production because production code didn't need it. This is test code in production. And why not to put in production code that doesn't belong there - read about Ariane 5 rocket.

Comment: That's what I'm saying: I_have_ used it in production. It's useful in production. It's also useful in testing.

Comment: But we are talking about OP's code. His production code doesn't need it. If it did he would already have that constructor. If you use those constructors in production and test code then I have nothing against that. I just meant that I think it is bad to add code that will be present in production although we know it shouldn't be used there.

Comment: And the OP already said it was a cut-down example, not the real production code. I just gave an example of how you could address the issue. We cannot know the OP's complete scenario. And, from my reading of their comments, the better approach is [Lie Ryan's](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/191036/2722). My approach is valid, perhaps not for the OP's scenario (which was only elucidated in the comments).

Comment: Peter/Peri, I agree with both of you to some extent.  I agree that it is useful, on occassion, to have constructor parameters to help define the initial state of my objects.  However, as I said in my original comment, having parameters for each property becomes a problem as the size of the object increases.  It also requires changes in 2 places if I want to add, remove or change a property (albeit in the same class).  Bottom line for me is to have constructor parameters only for those properties and values that are required to put the object into a valid state. This is almost always a subset.

Comment: So while that helps put the object into a valid initial state, testing the behavior of the object at it progresses through its lifecycle requires that the object be changed from its initial state.  My OP has to do with testing these additional states when you can't simply set properties to change the object's state.

Answer (score 1):

One strategy is that you inherit the class(in this case Document) and write tests against the inherited class. The inherited class allows some way to set the object state in tests.

In C# one strategy could be to make setters internal, then exposing internals to test project.

You could also use the class API like you described("I can certainly do this by calling Publish twice"). This would be setting object state using the public services of the object, it doesn't seem too smelly to me. In the case of your example, this would probably be the way I'd do it.

Comment: I thought about this as a possible solution but hesitated to make my properties overridable or expose the setters as protected because it felt like I was opening the object up and breaking encapsulation. I think making the properties protected is certainly better than public or even internal/friend.  I will definitely give this approach more thought.  It's simple and effective.  Sometimes that's the best approach.  If anyone disagrees, please add comments with specifics.

Answer (score 1):

To test in absolute isolation [the commands and queries](http://epic.tesio.it/doc/manual/command_query_separation.html) that the domain objects receive, I'm used to supply each test with a serialization of the object in the expected state. In the arrange section of the test, it loads the object to test from a file that I have previously prepared. At first I started with binary serializations, but json has proved to be a lot easier to mantain. This proved to work well, whenever absolute isolation in tests provides actual value.

**edit** just a note, some times JSON serialization fails (as in case of cyclic object's graphs, that are a smell, btw). In such situations, I rescue to binary serialization. It's a bit pragmatic, but works. :-)

Comment: And how do you prepare object in expected state if there is no setter and you don't want to call it's public methods to set it up?

Comment: I have written a small tool for that. It load a class by reflection that create a new entity using it's public constructor (typically taking just the identifier) and invoke an array of Action<TEntity> on it, saving a snapshot after each operation (with a conventional name based on the action's index and the entity name). The tool is executed manually at each refactoring of the entity code and the snapshots are tracked by the DCVS.  

Obviously each Action calls a public command of the entity, but this is done out of the tests runs that this way are truly **Unit** test.

Comment: I don't understand how that changes anything. If it still calls public methods on sut (system under test) then its no different then just calling those methods in the test.

Comment: After the snapshots are produced, they are stored in files. Each tests does not depend on the sequence of the operations required to obtain the starting state of the entity, but from the state itself (loaded from the snapshot). The method under test itself is then isolated from changes to the other methods.

Comment: What when someone changes the public method that was used to prepare serialized state for your tests but forgets to run the tool to regenerate the serialized object? Tests still are green even if there is an error in code. Still I say this doesn't change anything. You still run public methods so setup the objects you test. But you run them long before tests are run.

Comment: When someone changes the public method that was used to prepare the serialized state, the class that contains the Action<TEntity> to execute can not compile. Such compilation errors remind us to fix the states. As said, this is not a theoretical suggestion: it's how I ensure such kind of unit test isolation (when required), and I can grant that it works pretty well in real world DDD applications.

Comment: I don't understand one thing. How is that compilation error if I change public methods body, say someflag = true to someFlag = false;?

Comment: Changing implementation that way is quite rare, since it's dangerous by itself. Indeed with such kind of changes affect the clients in subtle and unexpected way. I can't remember of such kind of changes in the domain code in the last 2 years, since most of times if you change internal behaviour, you will change the external API, too. BTW... if you have other doubts about this testing approach, you can simply try it on real world domain models.

Comment: changing implementation without changing external interface is rare and dangereous!?   i would have to see your code to try it because im not sure I understand.

Comment: This sounds like a complex implementation of the Memento pattern where you are storing the Memento in a file.  I had thought about using that pattern but it seemed like a lot of extra work and duplicate code to implement.  I agree with Peri that this solution seems fragile.  I'm glad it works for you, but I'm not convinced at this point.

Comment: @SonOfPirate you are right, it's just a memento pattern applied to unit tests. I've never realized that. :-)
It's not that fragile anyway. You just need the proper tools.

Answer (score -7):

You say

> do try to apply best practices whenever possible

and

> the ORM we are using to hydrate the objects uses reflection so it is
>   able to access private setters

and I have to think that using reflection to bypass access controls on your classes is not what I'd describe as "best practice". Its going to be horribly slow too.

---

Personally, I would scrap your unit test framework and go with something in the class - it seems that you're writing tests from the viewpoint of testing the entire class anyway, which is good. In the past, for some tricky components that needed testing, I ave embedded the asserts and setup code into the class itself (it used to be a common design pattern to have a test() method in every class), so you create a client that simply instantiates an object and calls the test method which can set itself up as you like without nastiness like reflection hacks.

If you're concerned about code bloat, just wrap the testing methods in #ifdefs to make them only available in debug code (probably a best practice itself)

Comment: -1: Scrapping your testing framework and going back to test methods inside the class would be going back to the dark ages of unit testing.

Comment: No -1 from me, but including test code in production is generally a [Bad Thing(TM)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9023127/12570).

Comment: what else does the OP do? Stick to screwing with private setters?! Its like choosing which poison you want to drink. My suggestion to the OP was to put the unit test into debug code, not production. In my experience, putting unit tests into a different project just means that project gets closely tied to the original anyway, so from a dev PoV, there's little distinction.